# properties of an item in listview changes (or set to new properties) when the same item is newly selected again

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of Items. I added an Item with certain properties to the array list. When I add the same item to the array list again with different properties, all the properties of the previously added item are set to the properties of newly item. 
e.g If I add Car with Properties like Diesel and Sedan, again I add a Car with properties Petrol and Hatchback.

I should see `ArrayList` of Items like this:

```
[0] Car(Diesel,Sedan)
[1] Car(Petrol,Hatchback)
```

But I see like this:

```
[0] Car(Petrol,Hatchback)
[1] Car(Petrol,Hatchback)
```

Comment: cannot not be figured out without relevant code

Comment: I think your list contains the same reference twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list contains the same reference at both the indexes